# How to set values in textboxes

Tags: html, jquery

iam facing a problem while setting texbox value. What iam doing is, getting the id of anchor tag on click function and then split the id into string and setting these splited string into different string. the problem is i can set textbox value onlywhen i use alert() function without alert iam unable to set textbox value. here is my code

```
 $(".getPenalties").click(function () {
    var datas = this.id;
    var array_data = String(datas).split("#");
    $("#sbdt").load("../Account/Home/Defaulter.jsp?Staffdefaulter=1");
    var empid = array_data[4].trim(),
        name = array_data[1].trim(),
        dept = array_data[2].trim(),
        penalty = array_data[3].trim(),
        tabid = array_data[0].trim();
    alert(empid);
    $("#Empid").val(empid);
    $("#EmpName").val(name);
    $("#EmpDept").val(dept);
    $("#EmpPenalty").val(penalty);
    $("#hiddendata").val(tabid);
});
```

Comment: var datas=$(this).attr(id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your elements may not exist prior to load callback so, try using callback function of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to set the values, like:

```
$("#sbdt").load("../Account/Home/Defaulter.jsp?Staffdefaulter=1", function() {
    var empid = array_data[4].trim(),
    name = array_data[1].trim(),
    dept = array_data[2].trim(),
    penalty = array_data[3].trim(),
    tabid = array_data[0].trim();

    $("#Empid").val(empid);
    $("#EmpName").val(name);
    $("#EmpDept").val(dept);
    $("#EmpPenalty").val(penalty);
    $("#hiddendata").val(tabid);
});
```

Comment: @sudhir .. Is it work fr .net mvc .. by replacing Staffdefaulter as json method

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the input fields are loaded dynamically using the `load()` call, so you need to wait till the dom is loaded with the input fields, for that you can use the load callback function

```
$(".getPenalties").click(function () {
    var datas = this.id;
    var array_data = String(datas).split("#");
    $("#sbdt").load("../Account/Home/Defaulter.jsp?Staffdefaulter=1", function(){
        var empid = array_data[4].trim(),
            name = array_data[1].trim(),
            dept = array_data[2].trim(),
            penalty = array_data[3].trim(),
            tabid = array_data[0].trim();
        $("#Empid").val(empid);
        $("#EmpName").val(name);
        $("#EmpDept").val(dept);
        $("#EmpPenalty").val(penalty);
        $("#hiddendata").val(tabid);
    });

});
```